# Rectangle between the linking diagonal path using d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i am using d3.js and i have created the tree structure thats working fine for me.But now i am facing problem how to create the rectangle between the diagonal path.i am not getting any idea.`

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
......

/ Enter the links.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.target.level; })
.attr("d", diagonal);
```

can you please guide me how i can do this.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the rectangle between the diagonal path"?

Comment: means i want rectangle box between the diagonal path

Comment: Between the diagonal path and what?

Comment: you can refer the attached image..

Comment: Well, you have to calculate the midpoint between source and target for each path and add a `rect` element there.

Comment: can you please provide me any example for my reference..if possible

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841442/how-to-put-labels-on-the-edges-in-the-dendrogram-example) is a question for how to do it with text. The only difference in your case is that you would add `rect` elements instead.